# Bootstrap 5 elements, different disposition on different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have 5 elements that I want to put in a different placement on diffenrent screen sizes.
on desktops it will be 3 in the first row then 2 in the second

```
* * *
 * *
```

then on tablets 2 - 2 - 1

```
* *
* *
*
```

then on mobile each one in a row

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

how can I do the tablet one? if I put the first 3 in a row, I will have the following

```
* *
*
* *
```

Comment: Try to use the `@media` queries in your CSS file(s)

Comment: can you please give us the html code you are currently using? we need to know the code to help you.

Comment: if you put an example code it would be easier to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to start with mobile first in Bootstrap, so you can achieve what you want like this:

```css
.row div {
  text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.col2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.col3 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.col5 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col1 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">COL1</div>
  <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">COL2</div>
  <div class="col3 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">COL3</div>
  <div class="col4 col-xs-12 col-md-6">COL4</div>
  <div class="col5 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">COL5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
      1st Column
    </div> <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      2nd Column
    </div> <!-- col -->
    
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      3rd Column
    </div> <!-- col -->
    
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      4th Column
    </div> <!-- col -->
    
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      5th Column
    </div> <!-- col -->
    
  </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- container -->
```

Hope it helps.